# Apache camel route from kafka to another kafka topic on error

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel to consume messages from kafka topic and then process the message, while processing if an exception occurs, I redirect that message to another kafka topic and process that in separate route. so I have a route something like below.

```
from ("kafka1").process("someProcessor").end();
onException(Throwable.class).process(exchange->{exchange.getIn().setBody("Message with error details")}).to("kafka2");
```

Above code is actually sending the error message in same kafka (kafka1).

I solved this by setting             `exchange.getIn().setHeader(KafkaConstants.TOPIC,"kafka2"))` in `onException` process. Is this expected behavior? why would it ignore kafka2 and use kafka1 instead?

1. Version of camel used - 2.14.0
2. Kafka endpoint URLs:

Consumer:

```
from("kafka:" + ("kafka.broker") + "?topic="
            + ("offer.kafka.topic")
            + "&zookeeperHost=" + ("kafka.zookeeper.host")
            + "&zookeeperPort=" + ("kafka.zookeeper.port")
            + "&groupId=" + ("offer.kafka.group.id")
            + "&consumerStreams=" + ("kafka.streams")
            + "&autoCommitIntervalMs=" + ("product.kafka.consumer.auto.commit.intervals")
            + "&zookeeperConnectionTimeoutMs=" + ("zookeeper.connection.timeout")
            + "&rebalanceMaxRetries=" + ("kafka.rebalance.max.retries")
            + "&rebalanceBackoffMs=" + ("kafka.rebalance.backoffs.ms")
            + "&zookeeperSessionTimeoutMs=" + ("zookeeper.session.timeout")
            + "&autoOffsetReset=" + ("kafka.auto.offset.reset")
            + "&fetchMessageMaxBytes=" + ("kafka.fetch.message.max.bytes")
            + "&socketReceiveBufferBytes=" + ("receive.buffer.bytes"))
            .routeId("offerEventRoute").to("direct:offerEventRoute");
```

Producer:

```
to("kafka:" + ("error.kafka.broker") + "?topic="
                        + ("error.kafka.topic")
                        + "&zookeeperHost=" + ("error.kafka.zookeeper.host")
                        + "&zookeeperPort=" + ("error.kafka.zookeeper.port")
                        + "&groupId=" + ("error.kafka.group.id")
                        + "&zookeeperConnectionTimeoutMs=" + ("error.zookeeper.connection.timeout")
                        + "&rebalanceMaxRetries=" + ("rebalance.max.retries")
                        + "&rebalanceBackoffMs=" + ("rebalance.backoffs.ms")
                        + "&zookeeperSessionTimeoutMs=" + ("zookeeper.session.timeout")
                        + "&autoOffsetReset=" + ("auto.offset.reset")
                        + "&messageSendMaxRetries=" + ("error.max.retries")
                        + "&serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder"
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the bridgeEndPoint to true in your producer kafka end point. Otherwise it looks for the topic name in the exchange headers and uses that as the topic name for the producer also.

By default it is false.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide few more details about the code like,

1) Version of camel used

2) Your Kafka endpoint URL.

By any chance are you using 'bridgeEndpoint' attribute in your endpoint URL..

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, I updated all the details in the description